# From HHMMSSXXX to HH:MM:SS,XXX SAS

Tags: datetime, time, sas, format, transform

I have following input format HHMMSSXXX, for example 93552085, I want to transform it into time format like 9:35:52,085 in SAS. I have tried HHMMSS. format, t. format, but it does not help, i get weird output everytime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find an appropriate localization format you can roll your own using an **FCMP function** called out by a **custom format**.

Example:

```
proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.myfunctions.library;
  function myDateTimeFormatFunction(dt) $;
    length dts $20;

    dts = translate(putn(dt,'datetime20.3'),',','.');

    return (dts);
  endsub;
run;
quit;


options cmplib=(sasuser.myfunctions);

proc format;
  value myDateTime
  other = [myDateTimeFormatFunction()]
;

data have;
  do row = 1 to 10;
    datetime = datetime() +10 - row;
    _n_ = sleep(10,.001);
    put datetime= 22.3 @;
    put datetime= datetime20.3 @;
    put datetime= myDateTime.;
    output;
  end;
run;

----- LOG -----

datetime=1897993146.607 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:06.607 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:06,607
datetime=1897993145.622 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:05.622 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:05,622
datetime=1897993144.632 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:04.632 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:04,632
datetime=1897993143.643 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:03.643 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:03,643
datetime=1897993142.653 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:02.653 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:02,653
datetime=1897993141.664 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:01.664 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:01,664
datetime=1897993140.674 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:00.674 datetime=22FEB20:12:19:00,674
datetime=1897993139.685 datetime=22FEB20:12:18:59.685 datetime=22FEB20:12:18:59,685
datetime=1897993138.695 datetime=22FEB20:12:18:58.695 datetime=22FEB20:12:18:58,695
datetime=1897993137.706 datetime=22FEB20:12:18:57.706 datetime=22FEB20:12:18:57,706
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers!

The easiest way was: 
time=input(put(RAWTIME,Z9.),b8601tm9.3);